# Not allowed to load local resource: blob:blobinternal IOS/ WebRTC (cordova-plugin-iosrtc)

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, sip

I am developing a hybrid call app working ionic framework. For WebRtc i am working with cordova-plugin-iosrtc, and for signaling with pbx, i am work with sip.js library.

On Android devices, app works ok.

On IOS device, app throw next error:

**Not allowed to load local resource: blob:blobinternal**

**setLocalDescription() must be called with a RTCSessionDescription instance as first argument ...**

Thanks!!